# android sherlockActionBar styling action text

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

If i use sherlockActionBar with this code

```
menu.add(Menu.NONE, R.string.abc, Menu.NONE, R.string.abc)
.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_red_plus)
.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);
```

It shows the icon with the text next to it on the right in **UPPERCASE BOLD**. Now, setting asside android icon guidelines, how can i change the color/shape of that text?
This is what i've tried but it has no effect:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light">
    <item name="android:textSize">20dp</item> 
</style>

 <style name="MyTheme.Styled" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyTheme.Styled.ActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyTheme.Styled.ActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="MyTheme.Styled.ActionBar" parent="Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="background">@drawable/pdf2</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/logo</item>
</style>
```

Note that i'm not asking how to style the tabs text(which has answers on the site), but the action shown on the action bar and not the action shown in the drop down menu.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The color is changed:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light">
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/White</item>
    <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/White</item>
</style>
```

Based on the XML layout in the ABS library, you could use

```
Activity.findViewById(R.id.abs__textButton)
```

That should return an extended version of the Android Button, which can have a custom typeface. This probably isn't a good idea because I don't think it will work on devices using a native ActionBar. You can try and see.

Also, you should not be using `R.string.something` as the id. You should create an id in XML and reference it using `R.id.something` or just define an int in you class.

EDIT:
I did some testing and if you do `Activity.findViewById(menuItemId)` on an ICS device you get a ViewGroup with an ImageButton and a Button. I can't give you their ids, but you could use getChildAt to get the Button child and apply the typeface to it.